# Why do someone need an octal numeral system?

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, octal

I am sometimes heard someone claims that in the computing world we need the octal numeric system. As I haven't seen any confirmation IRL, I just ignored it, for me it is pretty common to hear a nonsense. But today I drew attention that the *strace* utility sometimes in the output uses the octal system, e.g.:

```
recv(3, "\22\4\5\22\22\4\207ZT\311\377\377\22\5\22\4\5\377\377\1\0\1\0%L\22\5\22\4\5oa"..., 255, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 54
```

So I decide to ask the question: why someone could need it? As an example, I can shortly argue why we need another common numeric systems:

**Binary**: to have a comfortable computing with a bits, as those have only two values.

**Hexadecimal**: as the *F*(15 in decimal) is just the half of a byte, and it is comfortable to represent a "full" byte with *FF*. And the binary one, of course, is too cumbersome for a big values.

**Decimal**: as this is native numeric system for a humans.

**Octal**: Hm... Have no idea.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers

Comment: Octal is useful when the byte and/or word size is a multiple of 3. Not so common these days, but it used to be the case for many architectures.

Comment: @PaulR I see, it was just the half of a byte in the past time.

Comment: 9 bit bytes and 36 bit words are two examples - you can treat a 9 bit byte as 3 octal digits and a 36 bit word as 12 octal digits.

Comment: Note also one area where octal is still widely used is for *nix file permissions, where there are 3 levels of 3 permission bits per level (r/w/x), and this can be conveniently expressed as 3 octal digits e.g. 777 = r+w+x on all 3 levels. Expressing this in a different base would make it much harder to interpret.

Comment: Can someone explain me why this question was marked as opinion based? Here is an answer -- about a byte size in some old CPUs. Is there could be another opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Octal represents 3 binary digits and also  it works in counts of eight, inputs and outputs were in counts of eight, a byte at a time.convenient way of converting large binary numbers into more compact and smaller groups. However, these days the octal numbering system is used less frequently than the more popular hexadecimal numbering system and has almost disappeared as a digital base number system.